# Getting sql records between two dates from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am currently trying to wrap my head around some SQL I am trying to build. What I have are two tables that appear as so:

```
Audit Table
id | user | action | date
---+------+--------+--------------------
 1 | dave | LOGIN  | 2020-01-01 00:00:00
 2 | dave | VIEW   | 2020-01-01 00:01:00
 3 | dave | LOGIN  | 2020-01-02 00:00:00
etc..
```

and

```
Page Analytics Table
id | user | page    | access date
-----------------------------------------
 1 | dave | home    | 2020-01-01 00:00:30
 2 | dave | account | 2020-01-01 00:00:45
 3 | dave | about   | 2020-01-02 00:00:30
```

I am trying to capture the number of times per user, per day that that user has logged in, and then accessed a specific page.

I am not expecting a particular elegent solution, but there may be something I am missing. I am figuring I am best building up a temporary table containing something like (gathered from the audit table):

```
id | user | login_start         | login_end
-----------------------------------------------------
 1 | dave | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00
 2 | dave | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:30
```

And then using this table, join with the page analytics, and counting the visits between these days, and then checking this count is above 0.

I am just trying to wrap my head around getting this intermediate table created. Am I going down the wrong path here? Are there better solutions?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How are you identifying that a login has been logged out?

Comment: Using the bound of the next login audit for that user. (Not pretty, I know, but there are cases where a user would  time out, and the LOGOUT wouldn't necessarily be captured)

Answer (score 0):

You can get page counts from your analytics table quite simply like this:

```
SELECT DATE(`access date`) `access date`,
       page,
       user,
       COUNT(*) hits
  FROM analytics
 GROUP BY DATE(`access date`), page, user
```

If you want also to include logins in your summary you can use UNION ALL to do this. (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64yHcewC1KjxfyejjqdaZv/2)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DATE(`access date`) date,
           CONCAT('viewed ', page) event,
           user,
           COUNT(*) hits
      FROM analytics
     GROUP BY DATE(`access date`), page, user
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE(date) date,
           'logged in' event,
           user,
           COUNT(*) hits
      FROM audit
     WHERE action = 'LOGIN'
     GROUP BY DATE(date), user
  ) summary
  ORDER BY date, user, event
```

Result:

```
| date       | event          | user | hits |
| ---------- | -------------- | ---- | ---- |
| 2020-01-01 | logged in      | dave | 1    |
| 2020-01-01 | viewed account | dave | 1    |
| 2020-01-01 | viewed home    | dave | 1    |
| 2020-01-02 | logged in      | dave | 1    |
| 2020-01-02 | viewed about   | dave | 1    |
```

I'm guessing about your logged-in / logged-out requirement though.